# Spec2006 Change in source code

Tags: benchmarking

I am working on some project for which I need to evaluate it with the Spec2006 benchmark. While my project actually instrument in source code and then compile the source to binary, I have found if I tried so; the building show following:

```
ERROR: src directory for 456.hmmer contains corrupt files.
       Is your SPEC CPU2006 distribution corrupt, or have you changed any
       of the files listed above?
*** Error building 456.hmmer
```

Can anyone tell me if there any way I could do so, like a change in some config file in spec 2006 or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way using following instructions:
https://www.spec.org/cpu2006/docs/runspec-avoidance.html

Answer (score 4):

For spec cpu 2017, you can put `strict_rundir_verify = 0` in the config file to avoid this error. I am not sure about spec cpu 2006, you can try that.

Comment: This worked for spec cpu 2006.